# Rotated UIView's frame Increase Decrease with UIPanGesture in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have created one UIView with apply of UIPanGestureRecognizer  for rotating with one finger and also increase and decrease its frame with one finge.

- Rotate view put on Bottom Left corner of UIView.
- Resize view put on Bottom right corner of UIView.

Let me write down some code lines of that.

```
//Rotate Apply with Pan Gesture 
    panRotateGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotateViewPanGesture:)];
    [rotateView addGestureRecognizer:panRotateGesture];

    //Resize View Apply with Pan Gesture 
    panResizeGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resizeTranslate:)];
    [resizeView addGestureRecognizer:panResizeGesture];

    [panRotateGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:panResizeGesture];
```

Here is the method for resize view with UIPanGesture with One finger.

```
-(void)resizeTranslate:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if ([recognizer state]== UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
    {
        prevPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.superview];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    else if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        if (self.frame.size.width < kFixW)
        {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, kFixW, self.frame.size.height);
        }

        if(self.frame.size.height < kFixH)
        {
            self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, kFixH);
        }

        CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:self.superview];
        float wChange = 0.0, hChange = 0.0;

        wChange = (point.x - prevPoint.x); //Slow down increment
        hChange = (point.y - prevPoint.y); //Slow down increment 


        self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width + (wChange), self.frame.size.height + (hChange));
        NSLog(@"self.frame : %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));

        prevPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.superview];

        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    else if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {

        prevPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.superview];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

And here if for rotating UIView with UIPanGesture with One finger

```
-(void)rotateViewPanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
    {
        deltaAngle = atan2([recognizer locationInView:self].y-self.center.y, [recognizer locationInView:self].x-self.center.x);
        startTransform = self.transform;
    }
    else if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) 
    {
        float ang = atan2([recognizer locationInView:self.superview].y - self.center.y, [recognizer locationInView:self.superview].x - self.center.x);
        float angleDiff = deltaAngle - ang;
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-angleDiff);
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    else if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        float ang = atan2([recognizer locationInView:self.superview].y - self.center.y, [recognizer locationInView:self.superview].x - self.center.x);
        deltaAngle = atan2([recognizer locationInView:self].y-self.center.y, [recognizer locationInView:self].x-self.center.x);
        startTransform = self.transform;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

Now the issue is,
Both resize and rotate gesture works fine.

**When i resize view with use of panResizeGesture it works fine, But if i apply once panRotateGesture and than wants to apply panResizeGesture it goes out of screen and does not  work properly.**

Any thoughts to solve this issue please.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame) clearly says:

**If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

If the transform property contains a non-identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and should not be modified. In that case, you can reposition the view using the center property and adjust the size using the bounds property instead.**

So, Just change self.frame into self.bounds in rotateViewPanGesture method

for example

```
        self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, kFixH);
```

to:

```
        self.bounds = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y, self.bounds.size.width, kFixH);
```

and your code will work perfectly fine.

**Update**

I have attached sample project which is used your code. you can use this code
[Answer](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yb0vzy0wao52bgt/SampeResizeView.zip)

Comment: Yes. i too had same proplem, I resolved it by following above way

Comment: i tried your code. everything is working fine. can you post your resizeTranslate method, after changing frame to bounds

Comment: I wasted my life to find that clearly speaking document. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late, so maybe you already figured it out, but your issue is during the locationInView: parts of your code.  You are trying to calculate locationInView of your actual view that you are trying to rotate, when you really want to calculate the locationInView of the superview.

```
-(void)rotateViewPanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
{
    deltaAngle = atan2([recognizer locationInView:self.superview].y-self.center.y, [recognizer locationInView:self.superview].x-self.center.x); //here change it to self.superview
    startTransform = self.transform;
}
else if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) 
{
    float ang = atan2([recognizer locationInView:self.superview].y - self.center.y, [recognizer locationInView:self.superview].x - self.center.x);
    float angleDiff = deltaAngle - ang;
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-angleDiff);
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
else if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    float ang = atan2([recognizer locationInView:self.superview].y - self.center.y, [recognizer locationInView:self.superview].x - self.center.x);
    deltaAngle = atan2([recognizer locationInView:self.superview].y-self.center.y, [recognizer locationInView:self.superview].x-self.center.x); //here change it to locationInView:self.superview
    startTransform = self.transform;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}}
```